# Convergence of random variables: Show that $o_p(1)\cdot O_p(1)=o_p(1)$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Show that if $x_n$ converges in probability to $0$ and $Y_n$ is bounded in probability, then the product $x_n y_n$ converges in probability to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good exercise to practice the convergence definition in first principle:

$X_n$ converges in probability to $0$ if and only if for any $\varepsilon_X > 0$, and for any $\delta_X > 0$, there exists some $N_X(\varepsilon_X, \delta_X)$ such that for all $n \geq N_X(\varepsilon_X, \delta_X)$,
$$ \Pr\{|X_n| > \delta_X\} < \varepsilon_X $$

$Y_n$ is bounded in probability if and only if for any $\varepsilon_Y > 0$, there exists some $M_Y(\varepsilon_Y) $ such chat for all $n \geq 1$,
$$ \Pr\{|Y_n| > M_Y(\varepsilon_Y)\} < \varepsilon_Y $$

Then for any $\delta > 0$ and $M_Y > 0$, consider
$$ \begin{align} \Pr\{|X_nY_n| > \delta\} 
&= \Pr\left\{|X_n||Y_n| > \frac {\delta} {M_Y} M_Y \right\} \\
&\leq \Pr\left(\left\{|X_n| > \frac {\delta} {M_Y}\right\} \cup \{|Y_n| > M_Y \}\right) \\
&\leq \Pr\left\{|X_n| > \frac {\delta} {M_Y}\right\} 
+ \Pr\{|Y_n| > M_Y \}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and for any $\delta > 0$, we can set
$$ \varepsilon_X = \varepsilon_Y = \frac {\varepsilon} {2} $$
such that there exists $M(\varepsilon_Y) > 0$, for all $n \geq 1$,
$$ \Pr\{|Y_n| > M_Y(\varepsilon_Y)\} 
= \Pr\left\{|Y_n| > M_Y\left(\frac {\varepsilon} {2} \right)\right\}
< \frac {\varepsilon} {2} $$

and there exists $\displaystyle 
N_X\left(\varepsilon_X, \frac {\delta} {M_Y(\varepsilon_Y)} \right)$, such that for all $\displaystyle n \geq N_X\left(\varepsilon_X, \frac {\delta} {M_Y(\varepsilon_Y)} \right)$

$$ \Pr\left\{|X_n| > \frac {\delta} {M_Y(\epsilon_Y)}\right\} < \varepsilon_X = \frac {\varepsilon} {2}$$

Combining together:

For any $\epsilon > 0$, and for any $\delta > 0$, there exists some $\displaystyle N_X\left(\frac {\varepsilon} {2}, \frac {\delta} {M_Y(\varepsilon / 2)} \right)$ such that for all $\displaystyle n \geq N_X\left(\frac {\varepsilon} {2}, \frac {\delta} {M_Y(\varepsilon / 2)} \right)$, we have

$$ \Pr\{|X_nY_n| > \delta\} < \frac {\epsilon} {2} + \frac {\epsilon} {2} = \epsilon$$

and thus this shows that $X_nY_n$ converges in probability to $0$.